# Titanium Alloy - Load view / window within a Tab

Tags: android, tabs, titanium, titanium-alloy

My application has a tab group (3 tabs). I would like my window to open within the tab itself and I don't want the new window to open on top of the tab. How can I accomplish this ?

```
var c = Alloy.createController('detailpage');
$.tab.open(c.getView())
```

This currently opens in a new window, covering my tab group.

Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Tab):

> On Android, the tab does not maintain a stack of windows. Calling open opens a new, heavyweight window, which by default covers
>   the tab group entirely

So I think the only option is to do so something like $.tab1.window = Ti.UI.createWindow(); etc

Comment: Yes, that definitely sucks. Although the documentation says that $tab1.<win>.setWindow should not be used.

Comment: ah yep..."You can only use this method to set the tab's root window before the TabGroup containing this tab is openened, that is, once the TabGroup is displayed, you cannot change the root window that appears in the tab." hadn't seen that.